# how we can get two values of array from model in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This code is in model...
i want to return these two values in controller.....please help me if you know

```
Array ( [disease_name] => magraines ) Array ( [disease_name] => brain cancer )
```

when i do

```
return print_r($qq);
```

then i get one value but i need two value that one value is

```
Array ( [disease_name] => magraines ) 1

function getDiseaseInfo()
{


             $spytoms = $_GET['syptoms'];

            foreach ($spytoms as $ss) 
                {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT d.disease_name FROM diseases d,syptoms s ,syptoms_disease sd
                        WHERE 
                        '$ss' = s.syptom_name  AND
                        s.s_id = sd.s_id_fk 
                        AND sd.d_id_fk IN (d.d_id)
                        ");
                    $qq = $query->row_array();
                    print_r($qq);
                }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your model `return $qq` only.

you are returning `return print_r($qq)` thats not the correct way.

print_r will print the entire array.

if you want to return your array values to your controller you have to return it like `return $qq;`

**Update 1**

I think you are getting last row's values,if im right you have to follow below steps,

You have to introduce a new array variable above your foreach

and assign your query array values to this newly created array

and you have to return that newly created array

```
function getDiseaseInfo() 
    { 
        $spytoms = $_GET['syptoms']; 
        $tmpArray = array();
        foreach ($spytoms as $ss) 
            { 
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT d.disease_name FROM diseases d,syptoms s ,syptoms_disease sd WHERE '$ss' = s.syptom_name AND s.s_id = sd.s_id_fk AND sd.d_id_fk IN (d.d_id) "); 
                $qq = $query->row_array(); 
                $tmpArray[] = $qq;
            } 
            return $tmpArray; 
    }
```

Comment: bro i want to return entire row and i want to send entire row to controller

Comment: function getDiseaseInfo()
 {
  
   
     $spytoms = $_GET['syptoms'];
    
    foreach ($spytoms as $ss) 
     {
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT d.disease_name FROM diseases d,syptoms s ,syptoms_disease sd
       WHERE 
       '$ss' = s.syptom_name  AND
       s.s_id = sd.s_id_fk 
       AND sd.d_id_fk IN (d.d_id)
       ");
      $qq = $query->row_array();
     }
     return $qq;
     
     
 }

Comment: @NadirAlyani you are welcome. mark this answer as accepted answer by clicking the tick sign if you are satisfied with the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post